# Counting line frequencies and producing output files

Tags: python

With a textfile like this:

```
a;b
b;a
c;d
d;c
e;a
f;g
h;b
b;f
b;f
c;g
a;b
d;f
```

How can one read it, and produce two output text files: one keeping only the lines representing the most often occurring couple for each letter; and one keeping all the couples that include any of the top 25% of most commonly occurring letters.

Sorry for not sharing any code. Been trying lots of stuff with list comprehensions, counts, and pandas, but not fluent enough.

Comment: Share example output

Comment: Does order matter? For example, would `a;b` and `b;a` be a reoccurring couple?

Comment: Yes, you need to define exactly what a couple is first before an answer can be given. pandas would be a good tool for this.

Comment: Add exampple output, please. Question is not very clear

Comment: Order does not matter a;b is same as b;a. Step one would be to get a sorted frequency list of the pairs. Then, for output 1, only keep the pair with a that has the highest frequency, and then do the same for all other letters. This means a, and others, can be kept more than once, if it is part of the "strongest" couple of other letters. For output 2 the top 25% of the freq list is kept.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you are saying. My answer is actually wrong below. I need to return one row for every single letter.

Comment: Ok now its finally correct  I think

Comment: @TedPetrou Thanks! Looks good. But I get `TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'`

Comment: @textnet `columns` should be `names`. Fixed below. I always get this argument confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer without frozen set.

```
df1 = df.apply(sorted, 1)
df_count =df1.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().reset_index().sort_values(0, ascending=False)
df_count.columns = ['A', 'B', 'Count']

df_all = pd.concat([df_count.assign(letter=lambda x: x['A']), 
                    df_count.assign(letter=lambda x: x['B'])]).sort_values(['letter', 'Count'], ascending =[True, False])

df_first = df_all.groupby(['letter']).first().reset_index()

top = int(len(df_count) / 4)
df_top_25 = df_count.iloc[:top]
```

------------older answer --------

Since order matters you can use a frozen set as the key to a groupby

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('text.csv', header=None, names=['A','B'], sep=';')
s = df.apply(frozenset, 1)
df_count = s.value_counts().reset_index()
df_count.columns = ['Combos', 'Count']
```

Which will give you this

```
   Combos  Count
0  (a, b)      3
1  (b, f)      2
2  (d, c)      2
3  (g, f)      1
4  (b, h)      1
5  (c, g)      1
6  (d, f)      1
7  (e, a)      1
```

To get the highest combo for each letter we will concatenate this dataframe on top of itself and make another column that will hold either the first or second letter.

```
df_a = df_count.copy()
df_b = df_count.copy()

df_a['letter'] = df_a['Combos'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[0])
df_b['letter'] = df_b['Combos'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[1])

df_all = pd.concat([df_a, df_b]).sort_values(['letter', 'Count'], ascending =[True, False])
```

And since this is sorted by letter and count (descending) just get the first row of each group.

```
df_first = df_all.groupby('letter').first()
```

And to get the top 25%, just use

```
top = int(len(df_count) / 4)
df_top_25 = df_count.iloc[:top]
```

And then use `.to_csv` to output to file.

Comment: Does the job. Thank you! The `.to_csv` files come out with lines looking like this `a;frozenset(['a', 'b']);3`in the first case, and like this `0;frozenset(['a', 'b']);3`in the second. Any smooth way to get them both to be formatted as `a;b` with headers being `source` and `target`?

Comment: To get rid of the frozen set use what was done in the second half `df['source'] = df['Combos'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[0])` and `df['target'] = df['Combos'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[0])` and the drop the unnecessary columns.

Comment: Can the code `df_count =df.groupby(['source', 'target']).size().reset_index().sort_values(0, ascending=False)`and `df_count.columns = ['source', 'target', 'weight']` be modified so that direction does not matter, i.e. a;b is counted together with b;a?

Comment: It is modified in the step above it with apply and sorted.