# Extracting from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
letter;Pairs;Count
abandon;frozenset(['abandon', 'dm']);1
abattoir;frozenset(['abattoir', 'year']);1
abbey;frozenset(['abbey', 'mean']);1
```

I want to write to a csv that looks like:

```
abandon;dm
abbattoir;year
abbey;mean
```

Standard pandas dataframe selection does not seem to work as `frozenset`complicates things.

Comment: Check out [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41076638/3707607) to your last question without the use of a frozenset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that the first line in your data frame is the header line so that:

```
print(df)

     letter             Pairs Count
0   abandon     (dm, abandon)     1
1  abattoir  (abattoir, year)     1
2     abbey     (abbey, mean)     1
```

(the round brackets around the elements in `Pairs` are how pandas prints `frozensets`)

You can change this into a data frame called `df2` that looks like this:

```
     letter Pairs
0   abandon    dm
1  abattoir  year
2     abbey  mean
```

By doing:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([df['letter'],(df['Pairs']-set(df['letter'])).str.join('')]).T
```

This works by first doing a [set difference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) between your `letter` and `Pairs` column in order to get the element in your `frozenset` that is **not** the same as the element in `letter`. You can then create a new `DataFrame` using this element and the elements in the `letter` column. Finally, you transpose that `DataFrame` in order to orient in the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this...

```
df["Pairs"].apply(lambda x: list(x)[0]).astype("unicode")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
print(X.apply(lambda x: ";".join(x[1]),axis=1).to_csv(index=False))
```

or

```
print(X.apply(lambda x: ";".join(x.Pairs),axis=1).to_csv(index=False))
```

where X is your dataframe might work